# How to prevent sibling elements from stacking?

Tags: html, css

I need a button group like the one shown in the code below and want to apply a `border-shadow` when the user hover's on top of a button.

The elements seem to be staking on top of each other from left to right, covering the right side's border-shadow.

How can I prevent this?

**I tried `z-index` and doesn't work on my code but I can see it working on other people's code snippets...**

```css
.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem red
}

div {
  display: flex;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a flex container with `display: flex` the `<button>` elements group together and the space in between each element is removed. To prevent this and allow your `box-shadow` to be more visibly seen, you could just add a bit of margin to each child `<div>` in the flex container.

If you don't want to add margin to separate the buttons, you can add the `z-index` property to the buttons hovered state so when you hover a `<button>` the box shadow appears and "stacks" above the other buttons. Remember, `z-index` only works on "positioned" elements:

- `postion: relative`
- `position: absolute`
- `position: fixed`
- `position: sticky`

From the Flexible Box Layout Spec, "Flex items do respect `z-index`" so if you have items in a flexbox container, they are eligible to utilize `z-index` without explicitly adding `position`.

```css
.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(233, 181, 12, 0.6);
  z-index: 99;
}

div {
  display: flex;

}

div > button {
  /* margin: 0 .5rem; */
  /* position: relative; not necessary for flexbox children */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Sorry for not being clear but I want my button group to be together but to still show the border-shadow.

Comment: @10110 Hi. Your welcome. Using `z-index` is what your after. I updated my answer if you want to have a look.

Comment: Thank, I actually tried `z-index` before asking here. It won't work on my code for some reason... But I can see how it works in the code snippets. I'm now thinking I have some CSS that prevents `z-index' from working.

Comment: It's probably not working for you because `z-index` only works on positioned elements like `position: relative, absolute` etc. I added some info about it in my answer. See if that works for you. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Ok, adding `z-index` on hover and `position:absolute`, kinda works but still looks like the element on the right is on top of it. If you do something like: ` box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(233, 181, 12, 0.6) ` you can still see the border of the element to the right.

Comment: Use `position: relative` unless you need to use absolute positioning with `position: absolute`. I will have a look at the new box-shadow you just shared and see what you mean. If there are too close together just add a little bit of margin like I suggested earlier.

Comment: Yup, with `position: relative` and `z-index` it works almost as I need. But as I mentioned if you apply transparency to the box-shadow, you can still see the button on the right on top of the one you're hovering on.  `box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(233, 181, 12, 0.6) `

Comment: @10110 Ok I'm glad it's almost working! I just added the box-shadow which is a yellowish transparent color and I see what you mean. Unfortunately that will always be the case with "transparent" colors because the elements are indeed right next to each other without any margin so the borders of surrounding buttons will be able to be seen in the background with a transparent box-shadow color. Using a darker color box-shadow would "hide" the border of surrounding buttons.

Comment: @10110 If you take away the `border` on the buttons, the yellowish transparent color will appear "in front" or "stacked" to the elements on it's left and right. But when you keep the default `border` color from buttons it's darker than the transparent yellow box-shadow hence you can still see borders when the button that is hovered moves up and is at the "top" of the imaginary z-axis.

Comment: I made some adjustments to my actual code (which is more complex) and I'm happy with how it looks now after making use of your suggestions. Thanks a lot, mate! :)

Comment: @10110 Your welcome! I'm glad we got it to work. Happy coding!

Comment: you don't need to add position:relative when dealing with flex items or grid items

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for the heads up. I updated my answer to reflect that flex items respect `z-index` ordering so the explicit `position` declaration isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is give a z-index to the hovered button

```css
.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem red;
  z-index: 1000
}

div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: But I have a question :D. Why does the snippet work as intended though?

Comment: @TannerDolby it has nothing to do with snippet, flex items don't need position set to work with z-index (it's a CSS feature)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok thanks for the heads up. So `display: flex` counts as "positioned" to allow z-index to work, and flex items respect `z-index` ordering. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn{
  margin:5px 10px;
}
.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem red
}

div {
  display: flex;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    BTN
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Give the button position relative. Then make the z-index: 100; on hover

```
button{
    position: relative;
}
button:hover{
    z-index: 100;
}
```